# React Native: error getting Invalid filename. Unable to add

Tags: react-native

I am very new to react-native and getting error while generating build for android.

npm version - 5.6.0
react-native - 2.0.1
node - v8.11.3

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..

> :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseShaders
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> UP-TO-DATE :app:generateReleaseResValues :app:generateReleaseResources
> :app:mergeReleaseResources :app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandRelease
> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateBundledResourcesHashRelease
> a80585d59325c208e3d120fe613639e73132576ef0e4e85a5de149e5d64c9e16
> :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processReleaseResources
> /Users/ravindrayadav/Documents/ZupplerMobile/mayaflavorsofindia/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_zupplernative_node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png:
> error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
> 
> :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 
> BUILD FAILED
> 
> Total time: 11.171 secs
```

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 OS?  and react native 0.56?

Comment: @AravindS macOS High Sierra version 10.13.5

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file also in question

Comment: you must have been tickling with the build gradle file of the application! don't. you?

Answer (score 0):

delete image files in android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* directory and rebuild it